# Selecting two tables takes too long

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to join two queries from 2 different tables and join them into one select but it takes too long:

```
SELECT
  p.pid, p.cid, p.date,p.headline,p.content,p.description,
  r.reg_id,r.cid,r.year,r.headline,r.description,r.url,r.extra
FROM printers p, readers r
WHERE 
  (p.headline LIKE '%val%' OR p.content LIKE '%val%' OR p.description LIKE '%val%' OR r.headline LIKE '%val%' OR r.description LIKE '%val%')
  AND (p.cid != 37 OR p.cid != 38 OR p.cid != 63 OR p.cid != 64)
  AND (p.status = 'online' OR p.status = 'active' OR r.status = 'online' OR r.status = 'active')
  AND r.headline_en = ''
```

It takes so long, phpMyAdmin (I'm using it to try this query) commented that there was an error on C:\Windows\Temp\*.myi . And if I'm using mysql client, it'd comment this I should raise memory limits.
Table `printers` has < 2000 rows while table `readers` has less than 1000 rows, which is not a big database... I prefer an optimization as I don't have access to mysql config in my host.

Please help me, is my query wrong or I have to change my my.cnf ??

Edit: if there's a lack of information. This query is for 'Search' function on a site, so there's no limit and they are two different tables with no share column.

Comment: I don't see any join condition. How `printers` and `readers` tables are connected in your query?

Comment: cartesian joins (that is, selecting from two or more tables without setting join conditions) frequently throw very large rowsets. Either define `join` conditions, or use `limit` to retreive the rowset in chunks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching two tables, without relating them in any way. This creates

- for every matching row in printers, all matching rows for readers
- for every matching row in readers all matching rows in printers

So the part of query relating to printers is run for **every** matching reader and vice versa. This puts this in the order of magnitude of 2000000 full table scans.

To fix this,

- either relate the tables (via a `JOIN` clause)
- or split the query in two, possibly reuniting them with `UNION`

**EDIT**

These are random thoughts in reply to comments:

- Using `LIKE '%val%'` makes index use impossible
- The first `WHERE` condition is selective on both p an r. It is my (possibly mistaken) understanding, that this precludes using one of them as a driving table, really creating a cross-selection table scan. Ofcourse the 2000000 is the maximum worst case (all matches)
- Anything I forgot?

Comment: "for every matching row in printers, all matching rows for readers" --- this not entirely correct. Apart of that - +1

Comment: PS: to fix #3: a join condition can be specified even for current implicit join, why not. Whereas "either relate the tables (via a JOIN clause)" by itself without `ON` would still cause Cartesian product

Comment: Not really 2000000 table scans, just 2000000  rows to filter.

Comment: @Goat CO: ... assuming there are no indexes :-) So "up to"

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect comments.

Answer (score 0):

Ok first off I optermised your query

```
SELECT p.pid,
       p.cid,
       p.date,
       p.headline,
       p.content,
       p.description,
       r.reg_id,
       r.cid,
       r.year,
       r.headline,
       r.description,
       r.url,
       r.extra
FROM   printers p,
       readers r
WHERE  (
        CONCAT(
            p.headline,
            p.content,
            p.description,
            r.headline,
            r.description
        ) 
        LIKE '%val%' )
       AND p.cid NOT IN (37,38,63,64)
       AND (p.status IN ('online','active')
            OR r.status IN ('online','active')
       AND r.headline_en = ''
```

also have you put indexes on any of your columns, those which you are searching against you should try and index

Edit. also you need to do a join on your data otherwise you end up with a massive number of combinations, so the above is only optimised on the bit after the 'WHERE'

Comment: Sorry, it still taking too long. Thanks anyway. I'll try to optimize the 'where' bit.